# localStorage not updating Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Basically i am trying to show the user an alert message only once, when he subscribed to newsletter.

So here I am checking whether the user has subscribed to the newsletter by setting a localStorage item 'subscribed' to yes. So that upon refreshing it will not show alert again and again. But when I refresh `(localStorage.getItem("subscribed") == 'no')` condition executes which it should not.

Tell me if I am missing something also if there is a better method available i would like to hear.

```
localStorage.setItem('subscribed', 'no')
    
    {% if email %}
      if (localStorage.getItem("subscribed") == 'no') {  
      alert("Thank you for subscribing")
      localStorage.setItem('subscribed', 'yes')
     
       }
    
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Looking at your code above, the statement `localStorage.setItem('subscribed', 'no')` will execute always.

Comment: Mixing Python with JavaScript seems like a bad idea. Let JavaScript handle it.

Comment: @anuragal yes I also thought that but how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the user subscribes make sure that local storage item of `subscribed` is set to `yes`. Then when navigating to a new page run the script below that checks if the local storage item is `yes`, shows the alert and then removes the key, preventing the `if` statement from ever being `true` again.

```
const subscribed = localStorage.getItem('subscribed');
if (subscribed === 'yes') {
  alert('Thank you for subscribing');
  localStorage.removeItem('subscribed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole code, but based on the above code snippet I suggest not to set any value for `subscribed` initially.

If no value set then it will return `null`

```
> localStorage.getItem('subscribed') or localStorage.subscribed
> null
```

Now your code should look like this

```js
{% if email %}
  if (!localStorage.subscribed) {  
      alert("Thank you for subscribing")
      localStorage.subscribed = 'yes'
  }
    
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped so I did it through cookies. Now it's working fine